# Plot a horizontal bar which doesn't start from the y axis

Tags: positioning, bar-chart

As stated in the title. I want to plot a bar which doesn't start from the `y-axis`(i.e., where `x = 0`). I try to use the `bchart` package but I fail to achieve this. For example, my latex code is like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bchart}
\begin{document}
\begin{bchart}[max = 100, step = 10]
\bcbar[text = A]{45}
\smallskip
\bcbar[text = B]{26}
\smallskip
\bcbar[text = C]{31}
\end{bchart}
\end{document}
```

and the result is as shown in the following figure. I want the bar A to start from 20, while bar B to start from 40. How should I work around it? Thank you in advance. [image]

Comment: No. With `bchart` they always start from `x=0` unless you redefine `bchart` environment. Are you interested in `pgfplots` solution?

Comment: Yes, if pgfplots could do this. I am reading the documents of pgfplots, but I can't do it still. Can you give me some advice about that. Thank you.

Comment: @user11232:  This thread is rather old, but were you offering a pgfplots  solution back then? If so, then you have what I am looking for. Would you please post your approach? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go. I have defined a new command `\bccbar` which takes an additional argument

```
\bccbar[text = B]{<end value>}{<Starting value>}
```

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bchart}

%-------------------------------------------
% Bars:
  \newcommand{\bccbar}[3][]{
    % Set defaults:
    \renewcommand{\bcbarcolor}{blue!20}
    \renewcommand{\bcbartext}{}
    \renewcommand{\bcbarlabel}{}
    \renewcommand{\bcbarvalue}{#2\bcunit}
    \renewcommand{\bcplainbar}{false}
    % Read parameters:
    \setkeys{bcbar}{#1}
    % Draw bar:
    \fill[color=\bcbarcolor,fill,draw] ([xshift=#3*(\bcwidth/\bcrange)]0,\bcpos) rectangle ([xshift=#3*(\bcwidth/\bcrange)]$#2-\bcmin*(\bcwidth/\bcrange,0) + (0,\bcpos-5mm)$);
    \draw ([xshift=#3*(\bcwidth/\bcrange)]0,\bcpos) rectangle ([xshift=#3*(\bcwidth/\bcrange)]$#2-\bcmin*(\bcwidth/\bcrange,0) + (0,\bcpos-5mm)$);
    \ifthenelse{\equal{\bcplainbar}{true}}{}{
      % Write value:
      \node[anchor=west] at ([xshift=#3*(\bcwidth/\bcrange)]$#2-\bcmin*(\bcwidth/\bcrange,0) + (0,\bcpos-2.5mm)$) {\bcfontstyle\bcbarvalue};
    }
    % Write text:
    \node[anchor=west] at ([xshift=#3*(\bcwidth/\bcrange)]0,\bcpos-2.5mm) {\bcfontstyle\bcbartext};
    % Write label:
    \node[anchor=east] at ([xshift=#3*(\bcwidth/\bcrange)]0,\bcpos-2.5mm) {\bcfontstyle\bcbarlabel};
    % Move vertical position downward:
    \addtolength{\bcpos}{-5mm}
  }%
%-------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
\begin{bchart}[max = 100, step = 10]
\bccbar[text = A]{45}{20}
\smallskip
\bccbar[text = B]{26}{40}
\smallskip
\bccbar[text = C]{31}{0}
\smallskip
\bcbar[text = D]{31}
\end{bchart}
\end{document}
```

[image]